# how we can find a smooth function to our data?

Tags: r, smoothing

Suppose I have this small data T

```
 69 59 100 70 35 1

 matplot(t(T[1,]), type="l",xaxt="n")
```

[image]

I want find a polynomial which is fit to data. (even over fit is ok)
is there any way that I can do it in R?

Comment: See `help("loess")`, among others. For instance, `sos::findFn('bezier')`.

Comment: Or even simpler, `lm(y ~ poly(x, 2))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the data.

```
y <- scan(text = '69 59 100 70 35 1')
x <- seq_along(y)
```

Now a 2nd degree polynomial fit. This is fit with `lm`.

```
fit <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 2))
summary(fit)
#
#Call:
#lm(formula = y ~ poly(x, 2))
#
#Residuals:
#       1        2        3        4        5        6 
#  7.0000 -20.6571  17.8286   0.4571  -6.7714   2.1429 
#
#Coefficients:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
#(Intercept)   55.667      6.848   8.128  0.00389 **
#poly(x, 2)1  -52.829     16.775  -3.149  0.05130 . 
#poly(x, 2)2  -46.262     16.775  -2.758  0.07028 . 
#---
#Signif. codes:  
#0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#Residual standard error: 16.78 on 3 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.8538,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.7564 
#F-statistic: 8.761 on 2 and 3 DF,  p-value: 0.05589
```

Finally, the plot of both the original data and of the fitted values.

```
newy <- predict(fit, data.frame(x))

plot(y, type = "b")
lines(x, newy, col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, now I have to play with it to get a better graph?

Comment: @user9272398 I don't find it a bad graph, it's a statistic fit, not a [Lagrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

Comment: with lm(y ~ poly(x, 5)) it is verrrrry good, I have one more question: if I want to write down this polynomial the coefficient are for x,x2,x3,x4,x5? there is no x1x2 or somwthing like that? becouse for lm(y ~ poly(x, 5))  I just have 5 coefficients. thanks again you helped me alot

Comment: in other words what is 5? the order of polynomial?

Comment: @user9272398 Yes, 5 is the order of the polynomial. And no, there is no `x1x2` because those are powers of the very same `x`. Note that you have 6 data points in the example, so that polynomial of degree `6 - 1 == 5` is a perfect fit and there are no degrees of freedom left. Not a good choice, just check out `summary(lm(y ~ poly(x, 5)))`.

Comment: well, I need it for a special case where over fitting is ok, so it works for me. now I ave 800 rows and for each of them I want to find fitted polynomial. should I do that row by row or there is a easier way to do that?